# Using 'previous' image versions with Docker

Tags: docker

I am experimenting with Docker, and fail to understand one thing - the docker tags. I will show an example:

I would like to use the, say, `openjdk:8u91-jdk` as I would like to build and test the version we have in production. However, when I try to create a container from this image, it can't be downloaded as it can't be found on Dockerhub.

Similarly, suppose I now use the latest as of now, `openjdk:8u102-jdk` and upgrade the production system for this as well. At some point there is bound to be an image update, and suddenly my build will stop working?

I don't want just use `openjdk:8-jdk` either as then I have no idea what is going to be used for the build.

I think I'm missing something. How can I use a specific, previous version of an image?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably take it's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/baaaf7714f9c66e4c5decf2c108a2738b7186c7f/8-jre/Dockerfile) and update the JAVA_VERSION and JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION environment variables to reflect the OpenJDK version you want to use, then build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

All a tag does is point to a certain group of file-system layers, which means that the underlying contents can change at any time. That is one of the things that other containerization vendors, and the appC spec, are working to address, usually by using something similar to a git commit hash.

However, on well managed public Docker container repos, most of the time there will be some abstraction that works around not having a static tag to reference.

From looking at tags the [OpenJDK repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/openjdk/tags/),it seems you are in luck.

The tags are (usually) structured as follows:

- *`latest`*: points to the most recent stable build of the most recent version. *This is usually dynamic*
- *`8-alpine`*: points to the most recent stable build of version 8, using [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/) for the distro *This is usually dynamic*
- *`8u92-alpine`* : points to a specific build of version 8. Usually will only be rebuilt to include security patches

---

That means that if you want to bind to 8u92-alpine, all you have to do is reference that specific tag (`openjdk:8u92-alpine`) when using your docker commands.

All that being said, if you *really* need `8u91`, even though there isn't a tagged build in the openjdk repo, you can still check out the [Dockerfile for 8u91](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/commit/a0a4970a343a3c021dad760f2281d20f61931e3c), build it, and push it up yourself.